# Convert End Quote to Apostrophe Javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

The below two strings have different apostrophes. I am pretty stumped on how to convert them so that they are the same style (both are either slanted or both are either straight up and down). I have tried everything from enclosing it in `${}`` to regex expressions to remove and replace. I am not sure how it is being stored like this but when I try to search for string1 inside of string2 it doesn't recognize the index because (I believe) of the mismatch apostrophe. Has anyone run into this before?

```
//let textData = Father’s
//let itemData = Father's Day

const newData = currData.filter(item => {
    let itemData = `${item.activityName.toUpperCase()}`;
    let textData = `${text.toUpperCase()}`; //coming in slanted

    let newItemData = itemData.replace(/"/g, "'");
    let newTextData = textData.replace(/"/g, "'");

    return newItemData.indexOf(newTextData) > -1;
  });
```

Comment: You have to put strings in quotes. `let string1 = "FATHER'S"`

Comment: _"I am pretty stumped on how to convert them so they are the same."_: they're strings - can't you just change the code?

Comment: @Andy I have tried a bunch to change the code. I have tried to replace it with a single quote, a double quote etc. but it always comes back as slanted or straight up and down. Perhaps it is not the apostrophe that is causing the issue?

Comment: @CharlesBamford sorry I made the question too broad. I was just putting those string in there as data examples. I updated the post with the actual function.

Comment: No, @Olivia, what I mean is why can't you change `FATHER’S` to `FATHER'S`? It's a variable. You can change it.

Comment: @Andy I am trying to do that with `replace` with no luck. Am I writing the regex wrong?

Comment: If a value is a string, wrapping it in \`${alreadyastring}\` is just extra work. If you can call .toUpperCase on a value, it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, your code won't run because you are not wrapping your `string` variables with `"`, `'` or `` ` ``, depending on the case.

if your string has `'` you can use `"` or `` ` `` like this:

```
"Hello, I'm a dev"
```

or

```
"Hello, I`m a dev"
```

but you can not mix them if you have the same symbol, so this is not allowed:

```
'Hello, I`m a dev'
```

here you have a working example of your strings wrapped correctly and also replacing the values to match the strings.

note: please look that the `index` in this case is 0 because the whole string that we are looking matches from the `0` index to the `length` of the `response1`.

also I added a case if you want to get the partial string from `string2` based on the match of `string1`

```js
let string1 = "FATHER’S"
let string2 = "FATHER'S DAY: FOR THE FIXER"

const regex = /’|'/;
const replacer = "'";
let response1 = string1.replace(regex, replacer);
let response2 = string2.replace(regex, replacer);

console.log(response1);
console.log(response2);

console.log("this is your index --> ", response2.indexOf(response1));

console.log("string 2 without string 1 -->", response2.slice(response2.indexOf(response1) + response1.length, response2.length))
```

Comment: thanks, sorry again the strings are just for data viewing purposes. they are in string datatypes when being passed to the function. But this regex worked! I was missing the `/’|'/;`  - thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do a search using a regex, allowing for whatever apostrophe variations you expect:

```js
let string1 = "FATHER’S"
let string2 = "FATHER'S DAY: FOR THE FIXER"

const regex = string1.split(/['’"`]/).join("['’\"`]")
//console.log(regex);

const r = new RegExp(regex)

console.log(string2.search(r)); //comes back as 0
```